# How to use a resource in new URL outside of main class

Tags: java, android

I can use:

```
mWebView.loadUrl(getString(R.string.web_app_url));
```

within the main class associated with a layout in my Android app without any problem, but when I try to use it in another class within the same Java file I'm having problems.

How can I use a string resource within a variable declaration as follows (last line of sample code):

```
class BlueBadgeParkingDotComReachableTest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    private PreLoadChecks activity;

    BlueBadgeParkingDotComReachableTest(PreLoadChecks activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        int statusCode = -1;
        String returnedContent = "";
        try{
            URL url = new URL(getString(getClass().getResource(R.string.web_app_status_url)));
```

To start with the `getString` method isn't recognised within this class and the usual fix suggestions don't pop up in Studio and I've been struggling with this for weeks now and having to use a hard coded URL string.

Comment: Just do `getString(R.string.web_app_status_url)`.

Comment: Did you tried using

URL url = new URL(activity.getString(getClass().getResource(R.string.web_app_status_url)));
You need context for getString.

Comment: @LoveForDroid you got it. Hopefully eventually I'll get the hang of this thing they call Java - right now everything I try end up with something seemingly simple like this, but which seems alien compared to other languages I've used. (If you post that as an answer I'll accept)

Comment: @LoveForDroid If you change your comment into a statement rather than a question, it is actually a very good answer. Since the sentence started with "Did you try...", I thought you were asking a question for clarification rather than actually answering the question.

Comment: @LoveForDroid Also, `getClass().getResource()` is unnecessary in Android.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for explaining in your answer! +1

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I originally tried without the `getClass().getResource()` but was getting other errors. I guess I was being misled and ended up with unnecessary 'fixes' in there.

Comment: @LoveForDroid I apologize for the misunderstanding. Your original answer had the right information.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It's fine. Glad it worked for FatMonk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getString()` requires a `Context`. Most of the time you call this from within a class which extends `Activity`. Since `Activity` extends `Context`, you get the method for free. When you need to call `getString()` from another class, you must explicitly use an `Activity` or `Context` object. Fortunately, you have one in your `AsyncTask`, so you can do

```
activity.getString(...)
```

Now you only need to get the right thing in the parentheses. Remember that in Android string resources are referenced with identifiers in `R.string`. This means that you need to do

```
activity.getString(R.string.web_app_status_url)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation (and of course for solving the problem)